# Error Creating Push Topic: 'Contract' is not supported

Tags: workbench, pushtopic

Hi i am trying to create a Push Topic using workbench and i am getting the following error.

`Error Creating Push Topic: 'Contract' is not supported` 
and my query is 
`SELECT CompanySignedDate FROM Contract`
How to get contracts using push topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following subset of standard objects are supported in PushTopic queries: Account, Campaign, Case, Contact, Lead, Opportunity, Task.

Refer this link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/supported_soql.htm